# "scalene --version" in a Makefile

Tags: python, makefile

On Mac OS X, running `scalene --version` (a python package) on the command line works but running the same line in a Makefile gives an error.

```
$ scalene --version
Scalene version 1.5.15 (2022.11.16)
```

Makefile:

```
check-deps:
    scalene --version
```

```
$ make check-deps
Scalene version 1.5.15 (2022.11.16)
make: *** [check-deps] Error 255
```

Comment: It gives an error because the program returns a bogus exit code.

Comment: If you run at your shell prompt `scalene --version` then immediately at the next line run `echo $?` to show the exit code you'll see it's not `0` (which means success) it's something else.

Comment: If you want make to ignore that error, you have to tell it to do so.  One way is to use the `-` prefix, like: `check-deps: ; - scalene --version`.  It will print a message but won't fail.  Another way is to use the shell to avoid returning a bogus error code; something like `check-deps: ; scalene --version || true` which always returns true.  But if your goal is to see if the `scalene` program runs correctly, this won't help because it will ALWAYS return true.

Comment: It's unfortunate that this program `scalene` has this problem (that it exits with an error, not success, when you run `scalene --version`).  If you know it always returns 255 you could check for that code and succeed.

Answer (score 0):

Running `scalene --version` at the command line followed by `echo $?` gives `255`.

Based on the comments above, I tried both suggestions, and they both work with slightly different outputs.

If the `Makefile` is like this

```
check-deps:
    scalene --version || true
```

calling the above like `make check-deps` gives

```
Scalene version 1.5.15 (2022.11.16)
check-deps completed successfully
```

When the `Makefile` is like this

```
check-deps:
    - scalene --version
```

calling `make check-deps` gives

```
Scalene version 1.5.15 (2022.11.16)
make: [check-deps] Error 255 (ignored)
check-deps completed successfully
```

Thanks for the help, MadScientist.